# The smartmatch operator is not working as expected

Tags: arrays, list, perl, smartmatch

Why the smartmatch operator `~~` says that `0` is not in `(0, 5..100)`?

```
print ((0 ~~ (0, 5..100)) ? "Y" : "N");
```

> N

Test it [here](https://www.ideone.com/jMNv57).

Comment: You are probably better off not using the smartmatch operator except in some rare circumstances.

Comment: `print grep($_ == 0, 0, 5..100) ? 'Y' : 'N'` does the same thing, without ambiguity.

Comment: ...and without relying on broken operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the right hand side an array reference

```
print ((0 ~~ [0, 5..100]) ? "Y" : "N");
```

or a named array

```
@a = (0, 5..100);
print ((0 ~~ @a) ? "Y" : "N");
```

or a ... whatever this is called (anonymous named array?)

```
print ((0 ~~ @{[0,5..100]}) ? "Y" : "N");
```

`(0,5..100)` is a list but it is not an array, and this is one of the places where the distinction is important.

Comment: I know a difference between list and array, but shouldn't this operator work with the list as well?

Comment: Maybe it should, but the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Smartmatch-Operator) indicates that the right operand ought to be an `ARRAY`.

Comment: @Ωmega, There's no such things as lists. "List" just means "a number of scalars on the stack". In this case, the number of scalars is always going to be one 1 because `(0, 5..100)` is evaluated in scalar context.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the broken smart-match operator. `0 ~~ ...` is specifically one of the reasons it's considered broken.

Use

```perl
grep { $_ } 0, 5..100
```

or

```perl
use List::Util qw( first );

first { $_ } 0, 5..100
```